# Change source e-mail notification address for Google Script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, email-notifications

Thank you for your time! Need help with google-apps-script.
I created Google Script code for E-mail notifications. By default, the E-mail notifications are sent from my e-mail address. I need to change the E-mail sender address to a different one. So, I changed the ownership of the script, but nothing changed, the script still sends E-mails from my original account. Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

changing ownership is not mandatory what you have to do is to run the script with the other account.

You create a script and probably a trigger and setup it from original account. To change email of sender to another account. Stop trigger and setup script from the other account.

The sender will now be the new account as it run the script.

Stéphane

Comment: Thank you! The solution works for triggered e-mail notification only. If the notification is created using Mail.App in Google Script, there is no triggers. Running the script under other account does not change the sender either. To change the sender, you need to log into the account that you want to be E-mail sender, select **Publish>Deploy** as web app and change the sender manually in the **Execute the app as** field.