# How to send automatic mail from different user to different user via google app script

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, html-email, gmail-api

I have made a webapp that can send email with values it gets as parameter after getting permission from the user. But what i want is when user makes request to the webapp the webapp should send the email to a specific address from a specific address if i provide the From address and its password programmatically in the web app

Here's my code,

```
    function doGet(e) {
  var name = e.parameter.clientName;
  var id = e.parameter.clientID;
  var getIns = e.parameters.insurances;
  var date = new Date();
  var iSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID").getSheetByName("Name");
  var lastRow = iSheet.getLastRow();
  var insurancesMail = "";
  var insurances = "";
  var count = 1;
  var message = "";

  lastRow++;

  for(n in getIns){
    insurances = insurances.concat(count+") "+getIns[n]+"\n");
    insurancesMail = insurancesMail.concat(count+") "+getIns[n]+"<br>");
    count++;
  }
  iSheet.getRange("A"+lastRow).setValue(name);
  iSheet.getRange("B"+lastRow).setValue(id);
  iSheet.getRange("C"+lastRow).setValue(insurances);
  iSheet.getRange("D"+lastRow).setValue(date);

  var messageHtml = "Some Html";
  MailApp.sendEmail("TO","Sub",message,{'htmlBody':messageHtml});

  return ContentService.createTextOutput('We have recieved your request').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT)
}
```

I am not able to find any function or library which gains access to a user account with its credentials and mail as that user. Is it possible to achieve this in any Senior

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589108/change-source-e-mail-notification-address-for-google-script, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463150/sending-emails-from-different-accounts-with-google-app-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MailApp specify mailbox sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288450/mailapp-specify-mailbox-sender)

Comment: Thank you for the response. It did not solved my problem but gave me some idea on how i can reach a solution. If succeeded i will post the answer